# Using a reference to call a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have ten data frames with names d01, d02,....d10. I want to be able to create a loop and call the file using the counter i.

For example saying

```
i = 03
summary(paste("d",i,sep = ""))
```

should give me the summary of the file d03. Is this possible? In my case the code generates a character "d01". Can I coerce this character "d01" in some way that it gives me the dataframe summary? So

```
summary(coerced(paste("d",i,ser = "")))
```

should give me the summary of fine d03, How?

Comment: Maybe use `get()`? Like `summary(get(paste0("d",i)))`

Comment: I'd say your separate data frames are probably better of if they were list elements. If you can make a loop to process them, you probably can make a loop to create them in the first place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the `get()` function:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(sample(10))
df2 <- data.frame(sample(10))
df3 <- data.frame(sample(10))

i <- 1
summary(get(paste0("df",i)))

 #sample.10.   
 #Min.   : 1.00  
 #1st Qu.: 3.25  
 #Median : 5.50  
 #Mean   : 5.50  
 #3rd Qu.: 7.75  
 #Max.   :10.00
```

---

Another option is to use `eval(as.name())`:

```
summary(eval(as.name(paste0("df",i))))
```